# "PHP parse error" vs "Parse error" in OS X Server Terminal command

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I am running a PHP script on a OS X 10.6 Server via Terminal like this:

```
cexa:~ soinro$ php /Volumes/dev1/cron/cron.php
```

And if the script has errors I get the output:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ccccc - assumed 'ccccc' in /Volumes/dev1/cron/cron.php on line 6
Notice: Use of undefined constant ccccc - assumed 'ccccc' in /Volumes/dev1/cron/cron.php on line 6
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /Volumes/dev1/http/~dev/_cron/cron.php on line 26
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /Volumes/dev1/http/~dev/_cron/cron.php on line 26
```

As you can see every notice / error is displayed twice: once as a "PHP Parse error" and once as a "Parse error".

The file I call is `/Volumes/dev1/cron/cron.php`. If this file has an error I only get the "Parse error", but if the files it `require`s have errors I get both the "PHP Parse error" and "Parse error" messages.

Why is this happening and how could I make it so that I get both messages (or just the ones without the "PHP Parse error") all the time;

For the discussion's sake here is the original code I call:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$crons = array_merge(glob("/Volumes/dev1/http/*/_cron/*"), glob("/Volumes/dev1/http/~dev/*/_cron/*"));
foreach ($crons as $cron):
/* there is only one file in the array */
require_once $cron;
endforeach;
/* this is the endforeach I leave out when I want an error in this file */
```

and here is the file it `require_once`'s

```
$mails = $db->result("select * from newsletter where status = 'sending'");
/* there are 3 elements in $mails */
foreach ($mails as $mail):
echo 'x';
endforeach;
/* this is the endforeach I leave out when I want an error in this file */
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: It the file setting up any error handler ?

Comment: the code is exactly as above. the first file has a `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` line right at the start, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you have both [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) enabled.

When `log_errors` is enabled, PHP writes errors in the file specified by the [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) ini setting (not to be confused with log_errors). If `error_log` is not set, the errors are wrote to stdout, that's why you are seeing them twice.

You have to either disable one of display_errors and log_errors; or to set error_log to some filename (or to *syslog* if you want to log to syslog).